# How to showing android camera simply

Tags: android, camera

I need some sample codes to just showing camera without any taking picture.
What is the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

In your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

in your code:

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for sample : Opening a Camera

```
public void open(){
  Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
  startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}
```

capture image :

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  Bitmap bp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
  imgFavorite.setImageBitmap(bp);
}
```

Add permission in Manifest :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

Xml :

Inside Relative layout take Imageview and textview

Try this.

Answer (score 0):

This link will explain everything a lot better than I could: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html

Comment: how to use in fragment

Comment: What I did is create the preview class: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#camera-preview and then place it in the layout: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#preview-layout

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); 
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```